# Laravel Mix does not emit my JS functions

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

Admittedly I am new to Mix and Vue. I have looked at the many similar questions on SO re Mix and can not find the answer. I am running a Ubuntu 20 production server on DigitalOcean with Laravel 8 and Nginx, and I access it via SSH.

Here is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/functions.js', 'public/js')
    .css('resources/css/default.css','public/css')
    .css('resources/css/app.css','public/css');
```

My mix-manifest.json looks suspiciously empty.

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

However, when I use Mix on my local development server ( Win10, L8, Apache) it all runs well, and the mix-manifest.json looks the same.

When I run npm run dev on DO it emits my app.css and app.js and that's it.  If I do npm run watch-poll and make a change to my functions.js it ignores it. I have watched the intro to Mix on Laracasts and read the Laravel docs on Mix. It all looks very easy.  There are loads of people with similar emit problems, anyone have any ideas I can look into? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put each of the `.js` and `.css` files on different lines, you could be overwriting one file with the other. Try putting them in an array instead

```
mix.js(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/functions.js'], 'public/js')
    .css(['resources/css/default.css', 'resources/css/app.css'], 'public/css');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried your suggestion and the good news is that mix does now watch for changes in my resources/functions.js. Great. However, it does not watch for changes in my css. My terminal output looks like this: 
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 44ms               4:34:10 PM

     Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  1.42 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app